# How to manipulate the HTML controls using directives

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a scenario, like i want to use a single HTML file for displaying the form(to get inputs) and use the same HTML for displaying the form (to display the filled value).

> Scenario 1 (Form input):

```
<input ng-model="a"/>
```

I want the above line to be like in scenario 2

> Scenario 2 (Form display):

```
<label>{{a}}</label>
```

If i pass a value into a function(or directive) like "Form" then scenario 1 should come otherwise scenario 2  will come.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You can use `ng-if='display_type=="form"'` then ... but i strongly suggest using different templates.

Comment: @haki Thank you, but can you tell why you're not recommending this

Comment: Well, if you need a different view for the same set of data i think it will be much easier to maintain and develop with separate templates. I mean, this is exactly what templates are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using `ng-switch`: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9y38G/6/)

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">

      <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="item for item in items">
      </select>
      <div ng-switch on="selection"> 
        <input type="text" ng-model='a.val' ng-switch-when="one" />
        <label ng-switch-when="two">{{a.val}}</label>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
<script>
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['one','two'];
    $scope.selection = 'one';
    $scope.a = {val:''};
}
</script>
```

Note that `ng-switch` creates new scopes, so in order to use the model from the controller I had to change `a` to an object, of which a reference is passed to the child scopes (which doesn't happen for primitives).